# App Never launches successfully again after Tombstoning. No exception thrown

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am having problems getting my app to restore/load from start after tombstoning.

It fails at the following line:

```
ServerCollection collection = AppSettings.GetSetting(AppResources.settings_servercollection) as ServerCollection;
```

This line is in a function that is called inside Launching and Activated.

The AppSettings class is this class [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145803/windows-phone-7-config-appsettings):, but I modified it to use a `object` instead of a `<T>.`

The debugger does not seem to enter the AppSettings function. It also displays the string i'm expecting to key on (`AppResources.settings_servercollection`), so I do not think that is the problem either.

Lastly, no exceptions are thrown. I have the entire section in a try, and breakpoints inside `UnhandledException` and `NavigationFailed` of the application, but I never seem to arrive at any of them.

Has anyone else experienced this before, or know what the cause might be?

Edit: Just wanted to point out that of course the app works after Cleaning/Rebuilding/Reinstalling etc.
Edit: I've been able to isolate it to this:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings Settings = System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
```

I found that out by placing it in each the Get/Set functions of AppSettings, and seeing it die directly on that line after entering the function. That said, Any ideas?

Comment: I have similar symptoms with my app as you have, although I am not using the isolated storage at all. Not receiving any exceptions, just the app hangs and the phone must be restarted...

Comment: gyurisc, have you made a post about it? I had a similar problem and it was because I changed my Assembly name, and did not update the solution properties to change the startup project.

Comment: I haven't got the time just yet to do this, but I will try this out. Thanks for commenting, it might just save my life :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serialization turned out to be working Okay. The real problem was that I had some infinite recursion going on in a property that I was saving.

```
public Dictionary<string, object> Dictionary
        {
            get
            {
                if (_dictionary == null)
                    _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                return _dictionary;
            }
            set
            {
                Dictionary = value;
            }
        }
```

As you can probably see, that was not going to end well. Too bad there wasn't a "StackOverflowException" or anything like there is in the console C# applications i've written before.

Anyway, thanks for the help.. Hope anyone else who has this problem may find this helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen problems with apps where IsolatedStorage is in an invalid state

I am guessing that this is the problem with your app

- as the example code posted in [Windows phone 7 config / appSettings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145803/windows-phone-7-config-appsettings) did not originally call Save() on the AppSettings after you Store a value (I've just edited it!)
- so this leaves IsolatedStorageSettings in an invalid state
- so the application fails to step past the static initializer of `private static IsolatedStorageSettings Settings`

To try to fix the problem:

- uninstall your app - this will clear up you isolated storage
- add a Save() to the end of your StoreSetting() method
- run again

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mention, I already had that Save() call. I've been using the class for months now and I forgot that I made that change a while back. I will try to reformat the AppSettings and see if I can reproduce anything different.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect a problem with serialising (and deserializing) your `ServerCollection` object.

Internally, objects passed to `IsolatedStorageSettings` are serialized as XML (using `DataContractSerializer` - which is probably part of the performance hit of using `IsolatedStorageSettings`). If your object can't be deserialized correctly you could see this problem.

As an alternative I'd recommend handling the [de]serialization yourself and then storing the serialized version in `IsolatedStorageSettings`.