# wp7: App failing!  Can not figure out where?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I think I've narrowed it down to this code in the Deactivation event:

Here's the thing...  When I put a break point in this code everything works fine.  The application does NOT fail.  However, when I take the break point off it fails.  What I don't understand is why the try/catch isn't firing.

I should also note that I commented everything out of this event with no break point and the application worked fine.  So it is something in this code...

**Could it be that the Save Event is not finished for the unsaved object and when it tries to reactivate the Activation event is actually the one failing???**

```
private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
{
    //MessageBox.Show("deactivated");
    try
    {
        //if ((Application.Current as App).infoSaved == false)
        //{
        unsaved unSavedPillInfo = new unsaved();
        unSavedPillInfo.RXName = (Application.Current as App).appRXName;
        unSavedPillInfo.RXNumber = (Application.Current as App).appRXNumber;
        unSavedPillInfo.DosageNotes = (Application.Current as App).appDosageNotes;
        unSavedPillInfo.Generic = (Application.Current as App).appGeneric;
        unSavedPillInfo.Instructions = (Application.Current as App).appInstructions;
        unSavedPillInfo.Reason = (Application.Current as App).appReason;

        unSavedPillInfo.Quantity = (Application.Current as App).appQuantity;
        unSavedPillInfo.Refills = (Application.Current as App).appRefills;

        unSavedPillInfo.Doctor = (Application.Current as App).appDoctor;
        unSavedPillInfo.DoctorNumber = (Application.Current as App).appDoctorNumber;
        unSavedPillInfo.Pharmacy = (Application.Current as App).appPharmacy;
        unSavedPillInfo.PharmacyNumber = (Application.Current as App).appPharmacyNumber;

        unSavedPillInfo.OrigDate = (Application.Current as App).appOrigDate;
        unSavedPillInfo.ReorderReminder = (Application.Current as App).appReorderReminder;
        unSavedPillInfo.ReorderDate = (Application.Current as App).appReorderDate;
        unSavedPillInfo.ConsumptionFrequency = (Application.Current as App).appConsumptionFrequency;

        unSavedPillInfo.PerscriptionUpdated = (Application.Current as App).perscriptionUpdated;
        unSavedPillInfo.PerscriptionUpdated = (Application.Current as App).doctorUpdated;
        unSavedPillInfo.PerscriptionUpdated = (Application.Current as App).detailsUpdated;
        unSavedPillInfo.PerscriptionUpdated = (Application.Current as App).pharmacyUpdated;

        unSavedPillInfo.Save();
        //}
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: I had some issues with `IsolatedStorage` at one point too when I was working with it. I would suggest trying to comment out code until you can determine exactly where the problem is coming from then posting that snippet so we can help you out.

Comment: @johnhforrest - I wrapped a try/catch block in those events and now without the breakpoints everything seems to be working.  idk...  seems odd to me.  So I guess the issue is resolved but I don't know why! :(

Comment: If you had made changes in your code without restarting the emulator that could have been the problem. The `IsolatedStorage` is cleared when you close the emulator so your program could have been trying to read in old data with a new format or something along those lines. Glad everything is working now for you though.

Comment: Any chance you can host the whole project? In the app.xaml.cs file you don't have anywhere showing where you save/load to the `IsolatedStorage`. I'm sure the exception is happening somewhere in there. Are you using a `DataContractSerializer` to write to disk?

Comment: @johnhforrest - see my update...  being that the debugger is deactivated it is making my debugging experience very difficult.  Any ideas?

Comment: I wrapped try/catch blocks around every save and load for the different iso storage classes I have...  Nothing is popping...

Comment: The way you describe the issue seems almost exactly the same to what happened to me when I was using `IsolatedStorage`. I think there is some compiler optimization or something that happens behind the scenes so the location where the break is happening isn't necessarily obvious. If you are able to host or email (john at johnhforrest dot com) me your project I can take a closer look.

Comment: I'll try to get something up for you to see today.  It might not be until the weekend though...

Comment: @Jeff V check my answer for an update. This sample works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hardly perfect but try putting a Messagebox inside of each of the eventhandlers. That way you can tell when each one is firing and see if one isn't firing.

Also you might want to unistall the application often to clear the IsolatedStorage. This is known to create issues if you keep running on the same installation.

**EDIT:** Yeah from what I have run into, the application can hang if you aren't properly saving to isolated storage. It can also happen if you aren't properly loading data from isolated storage. You might want to try each one seperately. Use a messagebox to make sure it saves and loads properly because VisualStudio will exit the current debugging session.

**UPDATE** What you should do is create a global variable called unsavedPrescription. Now when the user selects a prescription assign the global variable "unsaved" the prescription they selected. Note: you should not be assigning properties when the app is deactivating because it is very possible it won't save completely which leads to the app hanging. Instead all you have to do is assign the selected prescription to the global variable and change your code in App.xaml.cs to the following:

```
public unsaved unsavedPrescription {get; set;}

private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
{
    //Open up IsolatedStorageSettings
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = Isolated StorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

    //Use a model to save prescription
        //So create a name/value pair to store the prescription in isolatedstorage
    //Notice we used the global variable
    settings["UnsavedPrescription"] = unsavedPrescription;
}

private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    //Now you can easily load the prescription you saved
    //I'm reassigning the global variable that will contain the savedprescription

    if(settings.TryGetValue("UnsavedPrescription", out prescription)
    {
        unsavedPrescription = prescription;
    }
}
```

This greatly simplifies your code when loading and saving. Also you'll be able to test using the messageboxes like I said earlier, which isn't professional but it works nicely. Also your not running *too* much stuff when the app is trying to deactivate. THIS WAY WILL WORK AS I TESTED IT. The way you did it above looks like your running to much code while the app is deactivating which is probably why its hanging. Also this explains why when you remove it, everything works.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts.  What is weird is that when I wrapped a try/catch around the loading/saving in each of those events no errors occurred.  There was certainly an error there but the debugger wasn't catching it either...

Comment: @Jeff same here. The only way I could tell is if the messagebox displayed. No errors appear though. The app just hangs.

Comment: @Jeff have you considered other methods of saving your data to isolated storage? I have used IsolatedStorageSettings which saves values by key/value pairs. Check my answer for update.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem that seems similar to yours that wasn't actually related to the Saving/Loading from IsolatedStorage itself, but rather the property I was setting / getting had inifinite recursion. This caused the application to terminate before getting to Catch statements.

It might be worthwhile for you to turn off the Debugger stepping over Properties:
Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> Step over Properties and Operators (Managed Only)

```
public Dictionary<string, object> Dictionary
        {
            get
            {
                if (_dictionary == null)
                    _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                return _dictionary;
            }
            set
            {
                Dictionary = value;
            }
        }
```

[App Never launches successfully again after Tombstoning. No exception thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270026/app-never-launches-successfully-again-after-tombstoning-no-exception-thrown)