# Test App failing on Back Button... Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Ok this question stems from this question:
[wp7: App failing!  Can not figure out where?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530555/wp7-app-failing-can-not-figure-out-where)

I thought it was corrected but it is still failing.  I ripped out all of the app.xaml.cs code and it still crashing when the search button is clicked and the back button is immediately pressed.

So...  I decided to see if I could replicate the issue with a new test app.  Basically I have create a basic pivot application with the default Main View Model.  None of my code exists...

I press the search button and then immediately press the back button and low and behold...  The SAME THING HAPPENS....  It crashes the application, the emulator shows a blank screen and the debugger stops!

So...  That leads me to believe that I've found a bug in the emulator (I find this very hard to believe)...  OR, my Studio environment maybe is corrupted (I'm hoping it is not).

I'm not sure where to go on this one.  I don't know what the error is, and it is preventing my apps from being accepted on the market place.

Does anyone have any ideas?

**I made a screen capture of what I'm seeing:**

Notice that the 1st 3 search/back combos work as the boxes in the search screen are allowed to display.  However, the last 2 search/back combos don't work as you will see that the boxes aren't allowed to display...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XVht3OtBGaI

**The error report I'm getting from Microsoft:**

```
Comments: The application reactivate after deactivation and terminates unexpectedly.
Steps to reproduce:
1) Launch the application.
2) Select a vehicle.
3) Press the device's "Start" button.
4) Select the device's "Back" button.
5) Observe the application terminates unexpectedly and does not reactive the application.
This error is reproducible 8 out of 10 times.
```

The other error report from a different application:

```
Comments: The application terminates rather than resuming when the user attempts to return from a Search.
Steps to reproduce:
1. Launch the application
2. Select the Add + button
3. Press the Search button
4. Press the Back button
5. Observe the application terminates after a few seconds.
```

**I noticed that:**

When the following happens in the debugger:

```
The thread '<No Name>' (0xd1b0092) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0xd6900ba) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

That the project DOES NOT FAIL as described (100% of the time).  However, if I click the back button before this, then the application fails (100% of the time).

**Update #1: App.xaml.cs**

```
// Code to execute when the application is launching (eg, from Start)
// This code will not execute when the application is reactivated
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
}

// Code to execute when the application is activated (brought to foreground)
// This code will not execute when the application is first launched
private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    // Ensure that application state is restored appropriately
    if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
    {
        App.ViewModel.LoadData();
    }
}

// Code to execute when the application is deactivated (sent to background)
// This code will not execute when the application is closing
private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
{
}

// Code to execute when the application is closing (eg, user hit Back)
// This code will not execute when the application is deactivated
private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // Ensure that required application state is persisted here.
}
```

Comment: Are you handling Deactivated/Activated in any way? Can you breakpoint into them and see where something goes haywire?

Comment: @willmel - this is basic code.  See my question that I updated.  Basically the project is a brand new project with no code other than the Sample Data that comes with the Pivot application.

Comment: @Jeff V: Are you sure the app is crashing and it is not just the debugger quitting when you tombstone and then return to the app? Launch the app, then select the second pivot item. Now hit search and back, when the emulator screen is blank and debugger has stopped, run the app (F5) in Visual Studio again. If the app starts up with the second pivot item selected your problem is just the debugger quitting when the app is tombstoned.

Comment: @Praetorian - Well...  How you explained it, did occur.  Basically when I restarted VS again by pressing F5, the app started at the place it left off.  However, this issue is the same issue that MS is reporting that my app fails the testing (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530555/wp7-app-failing-can-not-figure-out-where).  Any ideas?  I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: @Praetorian - After further review...  I tried the same steps that you mentioned on my test app.  I selected the second pivot item in the test app, I hit the search button and then hit back.  The debugger stopped.  I hit f5 and the 1st pivot item showed up.  The comment above was on my built app.  I had selected an item that took me to a different page...  When I restarted the app (f5) the page that I left off on came back.

Comment: @Jeff V: I tried this in my own app and it came back to the second page of the app, I guessed that the pivot would show the same behavior, but maybe not, sorry.

Comment: Yeah I noticed the same behavior between the 2 different apps.  The pivot didn't go to the 2nd pivot, however, the app with multiple pages went to the page that it left off on.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @Praetorian - Does the debugger crash on you when you hit the search and before the white squares display on the search screen if you hit the back button?

Comment: @Jeff V: No it doesn't. I remember a blog post where that person was having unexplained crashes while saving stuff to isolated storage and navigating at the same time. He fixed it by making the UI thread sleep for about 100 ms before writing to isolated storage.

Comment: @Praetorian - you don't happen to remember the url for that post do you? :)

Comment: @Jeff V: I don't, would've posted it if I did :)

Comment: @Praetorian - what is weird though, is that for my test app I'm not using ISO...

Comment: @Jeff V - I don't think it's realistic to compare the behaviour you're seeing with the default pivot project in the emulator and what's happening in your app. Can you repro the problem with the new pivot project on a real device? If not, I suspect a bug in the emulator. Can you repro the same when not running under the debugger? I suspect your actual app is having diffferent issues otherwise this could be affecting everyone.

Comment: @Jeff V - The issue with your app sounds to be consistently reproducible in your app. If you were suffering the same issue around apps with a pivot sometimes crashing when returning from tombstoning this should be affecting all apps which use a pivot. I'm assuming that due to the high number of apps which use pivots and the lack of reports of other people having this problem, this is not the case.

Comment: @Matt - Thanks for looking at this...  The problem is I can't seem to capture the issue.  The debugger stops and the emulator screen goes black.  I have try/catch blocks around almost everything now and nothing shows up.

Comment: @Matt I updated the question to include what Microsoft is telling me.

Comment: @Jeff V - that only confirms my suspicion that what is happening in your app is not the same as what you are seeing with the default pivot application.

Comment: @Jeff V - can you recreate the issue Microsoft are reporting?

Comment: @Matt - I haven't side loaded the app.  I only tried to debug it through the debugger.  Someone on the MS app forum suggested it was a debugger issue.  I will try to side load the app tonight when I get home to see if maybe the try/catch blocks catch something.

Comment: @Matt/All - I side loaded the app and it worked fine.  I recently submitted the app and in the testing notes I asked to test it on a device rather than the emulator...  I got a notice that it passed...  I didn't do anything different so, I'm guessing they changed the way they tested it.  Thanks for everyone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after hours of banging my head against my desk I have found that the emulator on some machines are having the same issue I am seeing.

So...  The 1st thing I did was to wrap all my functions in Try/Catch blocks...  Even the smallest functions and the ones that can't error.  Then I side loaded the application to see if I can get it to crash.  When I felt I sufficiently tested it on my phone I re-submitted the app.  In the testing notes section I asked for them to test it on a device rather than an emulator.  I never heard if they did this or not, but they passed my app, so I'm guessing that they did.

Thanks to @Praetorian and @Matt Lacey and @willmel and anyone else that took a look at this problem for me.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed that If you create an new wp7 application this also happend.
Create a new application. Start it.
When it has started press the Start button and immidiately click the back button. It now says Resuming.. but nothing happens.
When you try to restart the app you only get to the splashscreen.

But I found out that if you build the app using Build=Release and dont debug the app (run it on a device) this does not occur..

Can you check if this is the case for you as well.. If so them im also in trouble

Comment: If it does not fail on a device, then you might submit the app with a request for a technical exception, suggesting that they test on a device, since the emulator appears to be acting incorrectly.  Or ask about the problem in the AppHub forums.