# Windows Phone 7, IsolatedStorageSettings "Remove()" not working, a bug?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm using [IsolatedStorageSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstorage.aspx) class in my Windows Phone 7 project as a key-value store to remember user preferences and login credentials in my app.

The problem is, when I invoke [`Remove(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.remove%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) method with the key and then I use [`Save()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.save%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) method to persist changes. `Remove()` method returns `true`, that means value is deleted. But when I try to get the value next time, I see that it is still there and not deleted.

Here's the code I use for deletion:

```
if (isolatedStore.Contains(key))
{
    isolatedStore[key] = null;
}

bool del = isolatedStore.Remove(key);
isolatedStore.Save();
```

Here's how I get `isolatedStorage` instance:

```
private IsolatedStorageSettings isolatedStore =
     IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
```

Where do you think the problem is?

Comment: The problem is somewhere **else** in your application.

Comment: See if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145803/windows-phone-7-config-appsettings

Comment: are you targeting the beta mango or the old release? try by removing the affectation of null value to the key when you call Remove, both the key and its value will be deleted

Comment: None worked, I couldn't reproduce the problem after a while though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this block in the following link.  I haven't tried to remove a key the way you're doing, though.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/17514c94-1f59-47b4-bb78-99694bfbb6b2

```
public static void DeleteObject(string key)
{
  IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Remove(key);
}
```