# variable enabled for the entire existence of an app

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am looking for a way to store a variable for the entire existante of the app (the date when the app was last refreshed) , an equivalent of the `userDefaults` in objective-c iOS.

I was thinking that i could use isolatedStorage, but it doesn't seem to be the best option considering that i am looking to store only one variable (a date string) and creating a file just for that doesn't seem like the shortest way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this 
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings

check this post
[Windows phone 7 config / appSettings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145803/windows-phone-7-config-appsettings)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a global view model (or equivalent) you could add a propety to the `App` class to store this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it to persist even when the application is completely shut down?  If so, then you will need to use IsolatedStorage.  If you only need it while the app is running then a static property of a class that is accessible globally would be fine.

Comment: IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings should work :) thanks!